# Store and attach cookies Webdriver Java Firefox Profiles

Tags: java, firefox, cookies, selenium, webdriver

I want to automate the 'Keep me signed in' functionality. Steps are as below,:

1. Open http://hotmail.com/
2. Type in the correct 'username' and 'Password'
3. Click on  "Keep my Signed in"
4. Close the browser
5. Open the browser again navigate to "http://hotmail.com/"
6. Browser should be able to directly sign in

As we know that WebDriver creates new session for every launch, so it will not be signed in for the second launch. So I created the firefox profile, added some of the cookies, closed the browser and launched and loaded the app again with the same profile. But it is not logged in.

I am not clear about storing cookies to the profile and using those for the second launch of firefox browser. Also it generates lots of cookies. Do I need to store all the cookies to the firefox profile?.

Comment: Can you show the code you used to set your FF profile in your Selenium test?

Comment: Why not, instead of closing the browser, you just navigate to a non-hotmail page?

Comment: "So I created the firefox profile, added some of the cookies, closed the browser and launched and loaded the app again with the same profile. But it is not logged in." Try to simply log in with that particular profile manually (as Firefox, if you're using Firefox, creates a _copy_ of the specified profile on every run) and then try it with WebDriver. It should be normally logged in. The "Keep me logged in" functionality works for me well.

If you really want to use this functionality via WebDriver, then you can't. Only the cookie saving/loading might be a solution. Will you show us your code?